# Setting license for Aspose.word registered assembly in azure using USQL code behind

Tags: azure, u-sql, aspose.words

I'd like to set the license for Aspose.Words dll, that is deployed on azure environment.
The dll is being used with some USQL code behind methods.
When setting the license in the code behind that is being called, it looks like it's being set successfully, but the resulted document (a pdf converted from word document) still has the watermark on it.

Probably the dll that was set with the license information is not the one that was actually being used?

Is it possible to set the license in the scenario described above?
If it's possible, what is the proper way to do that?
If it's not possible, is there a way to "pre-license" the dll that will later be registered into azure?
thanks.

**Update 1**: code sample for setting the license:

```
    static public string ConfigureLicense()
{
    var asposeWordLicense = new License();
    try
    {
        asposeWordLicense.SetLicense("Aspose.Words.lic");
        return $"License set successfully. {DateTime.Now.ToString()}";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "\nThere was an error setting the license: " + e.Message;
    }
}
```

**Update 2**:
here is the relevant code snippets that I used to set the license, as per the comments below

USQL:

```
@test =
SELECT sa.ConfigureLicense() AS License
FROM @t;

OUTPUT @test
TO "Test/LicenseResult.txt"
USING Outputters.Text();
```

Code Behind:

```
    public static string ConfigureLicense()
{
    var asposeWordLicense = new License();
    try
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"Aspose.Words.lic"));
        asposeWordLicense.SetLicense(stream);
        return $"License set successfully. {DateTime.Now.ToString()} , License set to {asposeWordLicense.IsLicensed}";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "\nThere was an error setting the license: " + e.Message;
    }
}
```

LicenseResult.txt content:

> "License set successfully. 3/21/2018 10:26:23 AM , License set to True"

The result printout shows the license was set correctly, but I'm still getting the watermark which indicates the Aspose dll that is being used is NOT licensed.
In this run, the usql job was run locally, not on azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem (thank you @Michael Rys for your comments - they really helped!):
The issue was around how I was registering the assemblies:

**(the wrong way)**: I was using Visual Studio -> right click on the project -> register assembly and then on the Server Explorer view, manually registering Aspose.Words assembly.

**(the right way/the way that worked)**:
when registering my own assembly, add the license file and Aspose.Words as "**Additional Files**" (and not "Managed Dependencies") - that way we ensure that all the assemblies are in the same folder on datalake store, so when we're calling `SetLicense()` it will be applied to the same Aspose dll that will later be used with our code behind.
[screenshot from Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EArs4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

How does the license work? Is it an extra file that you need to deploy together with the DLL? Assuming it is an extra file:

Did you try to deploy the code as an assembly with the license file as additional file and then use `REFERENCE ASSEMBLY`? Or if you want to use code behind, make sure that you include the additionally needed files with `DEPLOY RESOURCE`.

Comment: thanks for your comment. The license is an extra file. The only way to set the license is to call a method provided in Aspose dll. Our USQL code behind is deployed as registered assembly, and from the USQL script we are calling the methods in that registered assembly, which in turn call Aspose dll.

Comment: I did try to deploy the code as an assembly with the license file as additional file, but could not make it work.
Also tried to save the license file content in a db table, and then read that content and pass it to the SetLicense method - no good.
Another thing i tried was to upload the license file to every folder on the data lake store, which holds the Aspose dll and out own dll - no good.

Comment: Thanks... That is weird. if you deploy the license file as additional file, it will be placed into the working directory of the vertex and you should be able to reference it and load it with your code. Is the SetLicense method doing any external web service calls? Or does it just check the license file?

Comment: I believe it's just checking for the license file. Here is the code to set the license - please see Update 1 in the question.  Thank you very much for getting back to me.

Comment: Can you change the code to see if the file is actually there? Also, what context is `SetLicense` using to find the file name? Maybe it does not look in the current working directory but a specific location?

Comment: Tried the code behind approach and also verified that the file exists. The `SetLicense` method is passing, but still the result looks as if I'm still using the evaluation version of Aspose. 
Also tried using the other option of the `SetLicense` method, which is to read the license file as byte array and pass it as a MemoryStream. I believe that helps with the issues of file not found since I'm getting the license content before hand - still no good. thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I assume you are setting the license in the same vertex/UDO context as you are using Aspose?

Comment: After setting the License, You can check the value of the License.IsLicensed property. It returns true if a valid license has been applied; false if the API is running in evaluation mode. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

License license = new License();
license.SetLicense(MyDir + @"Aspose.Words.lic");
return "license.IsLicensed = " + license.IsLicensed;